Copy saved email to inbox with Mutt
I often save emails to disk files, a bad habit from using Mutt for 30+ years. How do I copy (restore) the currently open email on disk to my imap inbox? Preferably with a hotkey.

In Mutt, ! is a shortcut for the Inbox, so you can save the current message to that; eg by the s command
s!

This will mark it as to be deleted from the current folder so you might need to undelete it if you want to keep a copy in the disk file.
Similarly you can change to that folder with
c!

